# HTML parsing and extracting text

Tags: html-parsing, jsoup, text-extraction

There are a number of resources to parse HTML pages and extract textual content. Jsoup is an example. In my case, I would like to extract the textual content tagged with the html tags under which each sentence occurs. For example, take this page

```
<html>
<head><title>Test Page</title>
<body>
<h1>This is a test page</h1>
<p> The goal is to extract <b>textual content <em> with html tags</em> </b> from html pages.
</body>
</html>
```

I'm expecting the output to be like this:

```
<h1>This is a test page</h1>
<p> The goal is to extract <b>textual content <em> with html tags</em> </b> from html pages.
```

In other words, I want to include specific html tags within the textual content of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your result you can use this:

```
final String html = "<html>"
        + "<head><title>Test Page</title>"
        + "<body>"
        + "<h1>This is a test page</h1>"
        + "<p> The goal is to extract <b>textual content <em> with html tags</em> </b> from html pages."
        + "</body>"
        + "</html>";

// Parse the String into a Jsoup Document
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements body = doc.body().children();

// Do further things here ...
System.out.println(body);
```

*Instead of the String `html` you can load a file or a website too - jsoup provides this all.*

In this example `body` contains the html you posted as result.

Or do you need to select something like "h1 followed by p tag"?

However you may take a look at the [Jsoup Selector API](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

Comment: Thanks ollo. This is what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

You do it in two steps. First, as you have described, create a DOM tree using JSoup. Then process it using an XSL filter. In the XSL filter you can extract only those tags you are interested.

Comment: would that work recursively? tags inside tags like the em tag inside b tag inside p tag?